# Preventing captcha code from being cached by wp rocket plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, captcha

I use [Captcha Code plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/captcha-code-authentication/)

When the wp rocket plugin plugin is active, the same captcha code as before will be displayed every time the page is refreshed, This problem persists until I clear the cache wp rocket, What is the cause of this problem?
I think this is the function that generates the captcha code

```
function ctl_captcha_generate_code()
{
    //Settings: You can customize the captcha here
    $image_width = 120;
    $image_height = 40;

    $characters_on_image = get_option('wpcaptcha_total_no_of_characters');
    if($characters_on_image < 3 || $characters_on_image > 6) $characters_on_image = 6;

    $wpcaptcha_type = get_option('wpcaptcha_type');
    $wpcaptcha_letters = get_option('wpcaptcha_letters');

    $font = dirname(__FILE__) . '/monofont.ttf';

    //The characters that can be used in the CAPTCHA code.
    //avoid confusing characters (l 1 and i for example)
    if(!empty($wpcaptcha_type) && $wpcaptcha_type == 'alphanumeric')
    {
        switch($wpcaptcha_letters)
        {
            case 'capital':
                $possible_letters = '23456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                break;
            case 'small':
                $possible_letters = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
                break;
            case 'capitalsmall':
                $possible_letters = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyzABCEFGHJKMNPRSTVWXYZ';
                break;
            default:
                $possible_letters = '23456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
                break;
        }
    }
    elseif(!empty($wpcaptcha_type) && $wpcaptcha_type == 'alphabets')
    {
        switch($wpcaptcha_letters)
        {
            case 'capital':
                $possible_letters = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
                break;
            case 'small':
                $possible_letters = 'bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz';
                break;
            case 'capitalsmall':
                $possible_letters = 'bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyzABCEFGHJKMNPRSTVWXYZ';
                break;
            default:
                $possible_letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
                break;
        }
    }
    elseif(!empty($wpcaptcha_type) && $wpcaptcha_type == 'numbers')
    {
        $possible_letters = '0123456789';
    }
    else
    {
        $possible_letters = '0123456789';
    }
    $random_dots = 0;
    $random_lines = 20;
    $captcha_text_color="0x142864";
    $captcha_noice_color = "0x142864";

    $code = '';


    $i = 0;
    while ($i < $characters_on_image)
    {
        $code .= substr($possible_letters, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible_letters)-1), 1);
        $i++;
    }


    $font_size = $image_height * 0.75;
    $image = @imagecreate($image_width, $image_height);


    /* setting the background, text and noise colours here */
    $background_color = imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 255);

    $arr_text_color = ctl_captcha_hexrgb($captcha_text_color);
    $text_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_text_color['red'],
        $arr_text_color['green'], $arr_text_color['blue']);

    $arr_noice_color = ctl_captcha_hexrgb($captcha_noice_color);
    $image_noise_color = imagecolorallocate($image, $arr_noice_color['red'],
        $arr_noice_color['green'], $arr_noice_color['blue']);


    /* generating the dots randomly in background */
    for( $i=0; $i<$random_dots; $i++ )
    {
        imagefilledellipse($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height), 2, 3, $image_noise_color);
    }


    /* generating lines randomly in background of image */
    for( $i=0; $i<$random_lines; $i++ ) {
        imageline($image, mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height), mt_rand(0,$image_width), mt_rand(0,$image_height), $image_noise_color);
    }


    /* create a text box and add 6 letters code in it */
    $textbox = imagettfbbox($font_size, 0, $font, $code);
    $x = ($image_width - $textbox[4])/2;
    $y = ($image_height - $textbox[5])/2;
    imagettftext($image, $font_size, 0, $x, $y, $text_color, $font , $code);

    ob_start();
    imagejpeg($image);//showing the image
    printf('<img src="data:image/png;base64,%s"/ width="100">', base64_encode(ob_get_clean()));
    imagedestroy($image);//destroying the image instance
    $_SESSION['captcha_code'] = $code;
}

function ctl_captcha_hexrgb ($hexstr)
{
    $int = hexdec($hexstr);

    return array("red" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x10),
        "green" => 0xFF & ($int >> 0x8),
        "blue" => 0xFF & $int);
}
```

Comment: It's presumably caching the captcha. You'd want to exclude pages with the captcha from the cache. https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/54-exclude-pages-from-the-cache

Comment: I put the captcha code in the comments section of the products, I don't want to uncache the single product page, I just want the captcha code not to be cached

Comment: https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/1552-captcha-is-not-working "In order for the captcha to be compatible with page caching, it must rely on AJAX (JavaScript) method." "use a captcha solution that is compatible with page caching, like, for example, Google reCaptcha."

Comment: Before posting my question here, I did a lot of searching, I also came across this link you sent, the plugin doesn't have any java files to put it in the non-cache list.

Comment: The answer is simple: You need to either turn off caching on pages with this captcha, or pick a different captcha plugin. **The one you are using is not compatible with WP Rocket's caching.**